# how to query android database on basis of value stored in int array?

Tags: android

i have an integer array say int []  arr ={1,2,3,4,5,6} . I have a table named student in which their is a column named as id(contain int values say 1,2,6,7,8,12,13) .I want to get all rows that matches with any number from array arr.Please help

Answer (score 0):

First create a string from the array String should contain

String str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";   //depending on the number of elements in the array

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN (str)
```

Answer (score -1):

you should give more explanations. what databases are you using?

you could do a simple query in sql for example with:

```
SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,6 FROM student
```